# MIX IDE on MacOS El Capitan. How To Install, step by step please?

Tags: dapps, mix, installation

So I've been scouring the web trying to find a way to install MIX IDE and start developing dapps. But wherever I look, the steps seem to be outdated or contradict another site's steps. Now I'm very new to Ethereum and creating dapps, so if anyone could help a newbie out it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Mix is included in cpp, you'll have to download the file over here and you'll be done, just select mix and drag and drop it in your applications :)

http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/installing-binaries/osx-dmg.html

Or here (the same, but with more general options) :

https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/releases/tag/v1.2.9

Comment: Thank you very much. I was confused with the build from source part. Didn't know that i could just download the DMG and drag and drop. Makes life easy :)